# [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am having connectivity issue from Glue console while trying to connect to Redshift Cluster. I am able to connect to Redshift cluster with exact credentials from my Desktop.

I have followed the AWS documentation and have "ALL TCP" connections open for Security Groups in which Redshift cluster resides. Both Glue and Redshift are in same Region. Also Glue has been given AWSRedshiftFullAccess.

I am running a wall and appreciate if you provide me guidance to resolve this issue. I followed the steps recommended in other thread but no luck (Ensuring that DNSHostname and DNSResolution enabled.

Appreciate your guidance.

Thanks,

V

Answer (score 2):

Check if your redshiftcluster is ssl enabled or not, if it is SSL enabled, then you need to append the ssl config to the end of your host url. If ssl is not enabled, check the Security groups of your redshift cluster, it particularly needs TCP/Redshift port 5439 is open inbound.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `Add connection` in Glue and assign the connection you created for redshift to the specific job you are running? The link is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did use "Add Connection" in Glue.

I was able to finally resolve the issue after creating a brand new VPC and provisioning RedShift database in that new VPC and connectivity worked fine.

On the positive side, I am happy that the issue got resolved but not sure what was the underpinning issue.

Anyway, thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**make sure you disabled** 'Job bookmark' in the 'Job details' tab, for any development or generic job this is a major source of headache and troubles

also, when coping from **RDS to RedShift** notice this part in the dev guide:
Currently, an ETL job can use JDBC connections **within only one subnet**. If you have multiple data stores in a job, they **must be on the same subnet**.

in any case where your job has more than one connection string this subnet or bookmark things might be the problem

see [AWS Glue Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-dg.pdf) for more info